# Is it possible to change language of calendar at b-form-input's date?

Tags: vue.js, date, calendar, bootstrap-form-helper

I'm programming with Vue.js and i have a task: make my calendar at b-form-input (date type) flexible of language. My current language at calendar is Russian. I've try to do something like this:

```
        <b-form-input
            v-model="actualTimesModel.actualOut.date"
            :disabled="!avaliableSegments.includes('OUT')"
            @change="updateDate('Out')"
            type="date"
            id="date"
            :locale="$i18n.locale"
            :value="actualTimesModel.actualOut.date"
          ></b-form-input>
```

or simply just

```
        <b-form-input
            v-model="actualTimesModel.actualOut.date"
            :disabled="!avaliableSegments.includes('OUT')"
            @change="updateDate('Out')"
            type="date"
            id="date"
            locale="en-US"
            :value="actualTimesModel.actualOut.date"
          ></b-form-input>
```

to check could it even change a language. But it still remains russian. What do i need to do?

P.S. Change to b-form-datepicker is not a solution, my code breaks if i change